# Get pymysql.err.IntegrityError from sqlalchemy

Tags: python, error-handling, sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy.
and sometimes I have

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (pymysql.err.IntegrityError) (1062, "Duplicate entry 'john' for key 'name'")`
```

if I try to add a unique value that I had entered already, for example

if I do:

```
except exc.IntegrityError as e:
    return {"error": e}
```

it will return

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "gkpj",
    "statement": "UPDATE customers SET name=%(name)s, password=%(password)s, email=%(email)s WHERE customers.uuid = %(uuid_1)s",
    "params": {
      "name": "john",
      "password": "doe",
      "email": "joe@sco.co",
      "uuid_1": "bb4c7a5c-b9b8-11e9-8842-0242ac130003"
    },
    "orig": {},
    "detail": [],
    "connection_invalidated": false
  }
}
```

And this is not what I want to catch is

```
pymysql.err.IntegrityError => ((1062, "Duplicate entry 'john' for key 'name'"))
```

Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: The original error should be wrapped inside the `IntegrityError` and be accessible via [`e.orig`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/exc.py#L321-L322). Bit weird to see `orig` represented as empty dict in your output. Maybe a serializer interfering with it? Or how do you get `e` printed in what looks like JSON?

Comment: Awesome !!!!! doing -> `e.orig.args[1]` I manage to extract what I wanted, I am using fastAPI(ascync Flask like) and I got the JSON from insomnia(PostMan Like), and like you said since `e.orig` is an object <pymysql.err.integrityerror> It has been serialized properly! thank you so much!